# CakePHP Naming convention with words who have no plural form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

There seems to be many questions regarding cakePHP and naming convention. Although the documentation is pretty wonderful I feel like it could be more precise and complete.

I specifically have two question is:
1) What is the best practice when a word has no plural form? In my case the word `staff` is causing me head aches.
Below you can find my current understanding as it relates with a second model called "kid".
2) What is the nameing convention for when not using HABTAM and instead are using $hasMany and $belongsTo on each side of the join model.

```
                                                         Joining With "Kid"
Word in  | American English | Database | Model  | Controller       | Joining Table    | Joining Model | JoiningController
question | Plural form      | table    | Name   | Name             | Name             | Name
=========+==================+==========+========+==================+==================+===============+===================
Person   | People           | people   | Person | PeopleController | kids_people      | KidPerson     | KidsPeopleController
Duck     | Ducks            | ducks    | Ducks  | DucksController  | ducks_kids       | DuckKid       | DucksKidsController
Staff    | Staff            | staff    | Staff  | StaffController  | staff_kids       | StaffKid      | StaffKidsController <-- ReQ2: Is this correct? ReQ1: My interpretation of documentation.
.               ^                  ^                   ^                  ^
Staff    | Staffs           | staffs   | Staff  | StaffsController | staffs_kids      | StaffKid      | StaffKidsController <-- ReQ1: Seems to want.
Duck     | Ducks            | ducks    | Ducks  | DucksController  | duck_kids       | DuckKid       | DuckKidsController <-- ReQ2: Seems to want.
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Always use the `Inflector::pluraize('staff')` method to test the corresponding plural. This is the class which is used by cake for its naming convention. My try gave me *staffs*.
2. The naming convention for join tables is always of the form *plural_plural* and must always be alphabetical. That means: *kids_staffs*, *ducks_kids* and so on. Singular always remains plural.